# How to close a sequencer after its done playing

Tags: java

Whenever I start a sequencer using :

```
Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
sequencer.open();

// code....
sequencer.start();
sequencer.close(); //it closes the sequencer immediately with no sound being played
```

what is the way to make sure that sequencer has done playing with the sound and then invoke the close() method? I dont want to use time delay.

Comment: You can register an event for when you want to stop it. Check the [last part of this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-seq-adv.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) if you are using java8

It acts like promise of javascript. You can specify what method to be executed once a task completes. 
e.g:  you can do something like:

```
CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> sequencer.start())
 completableFuture.thenApply(s -> sequencer.close())
```